# Why does pygame stop working when I remove a print statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have some pygame code here I made:

```
#############################################################################
# IMPORTS
#############################################################################

import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

#############################################################################
# PRE-INITIALIZATION
#############################################################################

pygame.init()

#############################################################################
# CONSTANTS
#############################################################################

SW = 300
SH = 300

#############################################################################

WHITE = (255,255,255)
LIGHTEST_GRAY = (230,230)
LIGHT_GRAY = (205,205,205)
SORTLIGHT_GRAY = (180,180,180)
GRAY = (155,155,155)
SORTDARK_GRAY = (130,130,130)
DARK_GRAY = (105,105,105)
DARKEST_GRAY = (80,80,80)
BLACK_GRAY = (55,55,55)
LIGHT_BLACK = (30,30,30)
SORTLIGHT_BLACK = (5,5,5)
BLACK = (0,0,0)

RED = (255,0,0)
GREEN = (0,255,0)
BLUE = (0,0,255)
YELLOW = (255,255,0)

#############################################################################

SYS_FONT = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 30)

#############################################################################
# GLOBAL VARIABLES
#############################################################################

state = ""

#############################################################################
# CLASSES
##############################################################################

#############################################################################
# FUNCTIONS
#############################################################################

def addTuples(a,b):
    for i in range(len(a)):
        a[i] += b[i]

def set_state(newstate="",init_function=None):
    global state
    state=newstate
    if init_function!=None:init_function()
    return state

def get_state():
    return state

#############################################################################

def initSplashScreen():
    screen.fill(BLACK)

def initGameScreen():
    pass

#############################################################################

def quitEvent():

    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

def updateEvent():

    checkEvents()

    if get_state() == "splash":
        drawSplashScreen()

    elif get_state() == "game":
        drawGameScreen()

#############################################################################

def checkEvents():

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == QUIT:
            quitEvent()

def checkSplashScreenEvents():

    print("naff")

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == KEYUP:
            print("saff")
            set_state("game",initGameScreen)

def checkGameScreenEvents():

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == KEYUP:

            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                set_state("pause")

def checkPauseScreenEvents():

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            set_state("game")

#############################################################################

def drawText(text,color,loc):
    text_obj = SYS_FONT.render(text, True, color)
    screen.blit(text_obj,loc)

#############################################################################

def drawSplashScreen():

    checkSplashScreenEvents()

    drawText("Grid Game",RED,(95,50))
    drawText("Press SPACE to begin!",YELLOW,(35,100))

def drawGameScreen():

    checkGameScreenEvents()

    screen.fill(BLACK)

    drawText("Game",BLUE,(95,50))

def drawPauseScreen():

    checkPauseScreenEvents()

    drawText("Paused",GREEN,(115,50))
    drawText("Press ANY KEY to continue!",YELLOW,(15,100))

#############################################################################
# INITIALIZATION
#############################################################################

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SW,SH))
pygame.display.set_caption("Grid")

set_state("splash",initSplashScreen)

#############################################################################
# PROGRAM STARTS HERE
#############################################################################

while True:

    updateEvent()
    pygame.display.update()
```

When I run the program I can press 'space' key and it says 'game' in blue on the screen with a black background.

However, when I remove the print statement in checkSplashScreenEvents function: `print("naff")` the program no longer works correctly. When I press 'space' about twenty times it works after 10 seconds or so...

The print statements were only used for testing to make sure the function was called earlier on when I was creating this program.

I thought the python Idle IDE might have been glitching out so I got out of Idle and when back in. This did not fix the problem.

Does anyone know what is going on here, why this is happening?
And how to fix it?

Thank you, in advance.

Comment: Off-topic but I laughed at _"when I press space about twenty times it works after 10 seconds or so"_. Love the detail.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll update my code, once I can get this code to work. I have no idea what is happening.

Comment: I suggest you try running this from the command-line rather than IDLE.  I have experienced issues in the past using an IDE which is using TK when developing TK apps.

Comment: Still doesn't work. It makes no sense!

Comment: @FredrikRosenqvist: No - pygame actually almost requires event.get to be called in a `for` loop. The code could make the `get` call happen in a simple place, instead of across several functions, but that is another matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not making *ANY* pause between frames or event checking-  the CPU and I/O are overloaded at maximum. The print statement would provide a brief relief to the system.

Try just adding a `pygame.time.delay(30)` or so immediately after calling `display.update()`.

Now, with a little more calm, the real problem is that you are making calls to `pygame.event.get` in more than one location in your code, and doing that in your loop. That call is destructive in a way that it does consume any pending events. The print would introduce a small pause between calls to `.get` so that a `KEYUP` event eventually has a chance to sneak-in between the calls to `event.get` in your `checkEvents` method and the one in `checkSplashScreenEvents` method.

You'd better reorganize your code so that you call `event.get` in ONE single place-  otherwise your code will be unmaintainable (it is already hard to follow, and there is almost nothing in there) - for example, try to set an event callback for each of the game states - the callback gets a list of the ongoing events - from a single `getEvents` method.

For the code as it is to run, just replace your checkEvents for one with a non-destructive way to check for a quit event - for example:

```
def checkEvents():
    if pygame.event.peek(QUIT):
        quitEvent()
```

Comment: Doesn't make a difference... I see what you are saying about the print. I added the delay to the end of the loop. Still doesn't work. I normally add that the delay once I'm done coding the start of the game and getting things to work.

Comment: You should have the delay anyway - even if only for a minimal value. I will take a deeper look on the code.

Comment: Ok. Did you run the code yourself? If so, does it work for you?

Comment: You should call `pygame.event.pump` as well

Comment: @jsbueno You should only call pygame.event.pump() if you are not calling event.get(). http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump

Comment: "You need" is different than "you should" -  the extra call won't do any harm.  (Although, I agree it won't solve the OP's problem)

Comment: I had now - the checkEvent suggestion above is a fix.

Comment: My code is raising an error, because I used the peek with a key event. If using peek with key event, how do I do: `event.key`?

Comment: Your code won't  work if you just add peek everywhere, Because the event queue will get larger and larger with your unconsumed events. Please check the docs at http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html - `peek` does not return the event - just returns True if an event of the given kind is present.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll change up the event system properly and see if my program works properly.

Comment: Brilliant! Fixed the problem. The game seems to be working fine now! Thank you very much for the help. Better remember that for next time.